# How to get the address of the reference variable in pass by reference?

Tags: c++

In below code snippet , while using **&** with reference variable , we are getting the address of the variable to which the reference variable points but during a function call , the reference variable would have been allocated on the stack frame , so how to get that address value  ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void modify(int& x)
{
    x=9;
    cout<<&x<<endl<<x<<endl;
}
int main() {

    int a=8;
    modify(a);
cout<<&a<<endl<<a;  
    return 0;
}
```

Here both &x and &a print same value , which is the address of the variable a , so is there any way by which we can get the address of the reference variable x ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what a reference is.

Comment: Why do you think they would have different addresses?

Comment: You 're already getting the address of `x`. `&x`

Comment: A reference variable is an alias, that is, another name for an already existing variable.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing.

A reference is a synonym. It's a different name for the same object. A name does not have an address. It's just an idea.